# Make property reactive, props Vuejs2 data binding

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I'm having hard times with props in Vue-cli, here is my code:

src/App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <!-- Components -->
    <Book v-bind:dataBook="dataBook"></Book>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
/* Import components here */
import Book from './components/Book.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Book
  },
  data() {
    return {
      dataBook: {
        complete: false,
        author: ''
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

src/components/Book.vue:

```
<template>
  <section id="book">
    <form>
      <div>
        <h2>Book</h2>
        <label>Author:</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="author" v-on:keyup="formatComplete">

        <transition name="fade">
          <div v-show="complete">
            <br />
            <h4>
              Book Author:
            </h4>
            <p>{{author}}.</p>
          </div>
        </transition>

      </div>
    </form>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['dataBook'],
  name: 'Book',
  data() {
    return { }
  },
  methods: {
    formatComplete: function() {
      if (this.author.length >= 1){
        this.complete = true
        console.log('the value of complete is:' + this.complete)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Vue Warns:

- Property or method "author" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
- Property or method "complete" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child component (Book.vue) does not have `complete` or `author` props, on the other hand, it does have a `dataBook` prop which does have `author` and `complete` properties inside it. So to access those values you have to use `dataBook.author` instead of `author` in the Book component.